# Send System Wide Key-press Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to learn more about Android development, and I think I have hit a tough patch. Basically, I want to be able to send a "fake" key-press to the entire android system. For example, lets say I have my music player going and I want to pause the music. I should be able to send:

```
KeyEvent eventPause = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
```

System wide so it will stop/pause what ever media event is playing. The problem is, I keep finding things online about an instrumentation class, and some other weird classes that I either will have trouble compiling or has been taken out of the android API.

Does anyone know a way I can do this? I have a rooted phone, so a solution that requires root is perfectly fine for me.

Thanks!